# Can there be identical elliptic curve groups of points from different irreducible polynomials in binary extension fields?

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field, group-theory

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a binary extension field $GF(2^m)$, with constructing polynomial $f(z)$ be an irreducible, primitive polynomial over $GF(2)$, and let $G(x_g,y_g)$ be a generator point on the curve.

Is there any possibility that two (or more) different $f(z)$ can produce **exactly** the same GAL group for an elliptic curve (same polynomials as elements)? We do not allow adjustments of coefficients in the curve's equation.

For example, for $GF(2^{233})$ is there any case that e.g. the following irreducible constructing polynomials $f_1(z): z^{233} + z^{74} + 1$ and $f_2(z): z^{233}+z^{159}+1$ to produce identical elliptic curve point groups as elements $\in GF(2^{233})$?

My question definitely relates to a group isomorphism, as a function that maps a 1-1 correspondence between the elements of a group under group operations, but I wonder if it can go beyond that. For example, let a group isomorphism between elements of a Group $GF(2^m)$. Can this isomorphism go beyond group operations for any given tuple of elements $x_i$ and $x_j$ and perserve function mappings beyond group operations? For example, for scalar $k$ and the previously defined ECC generator point $G$, Point $P = k∗G$ is a different point for group $GF(2^m)$ if produced under different irreducible constructing polynomials. My question is if a point like this can indeed perserve more mappings/direct correspondences beyond group operations (in this context, both points $P$ will produce the same field trace, or the same Norm, or Half trace results when solving $z^2+z=λ$.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Do coefficients of $E$ change when $f$ changes? What are "identical elliptic curve point groups"? Do you only mean there is some isomorphism between the two groups, or do you additionally require that isomorphic points have the same $x$ and $y$ coordinates? Unless I err, the first follows from isomorphism of various instances of $\operatorname{GF}(2^m)$ for different irreducible $f$, if we allow for adjustment of coefficients of $E$ per the field isomorphism. Independently, is there a reason to specify that $f$ is primitive?

Comment: Thanks @fgrieu, useful comment for clarity. Ok so, first of all, no we do not allow for adjustment of coefficients in the curve's equation. I am talking about exactly the same curve. Second, I am talking about having the exact same coordinates operate in the same way. For example, when calculating the trace $Tr(x)$ of a specific coordinate x, which is an element in GF to solve the Equation $x^2 + x = w$ in Binary Fields, then the Trace should always give the same output in both cases, despite using different $f_1$ anf $f_2$s.

Comment: I am confused by this. At least to me the phrase *the same curve* is meaningless without specifying a presentation of the field. Using the field automorphism between the fields defined by $f_1$ and $f_2$ respectively must also be applied to the coefficients of the equation of the elliptic curve. Otherwise it is not *the same curve* in any sensible way.

Comment: Anyway, when you do it right, applying the isomorphism to the coefficients in the equation of the curvem the resulting groups will be isomorphic also. Is the distinction between *identical* and *isomorphic* clear to you? Sorry for asking, a veteran algebra teacher here :-).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, afaik a group isomorphism is a function that maps a 1-1 correspondence between the elements of a group under group operations. What I am saying is definitely an isomorphism but I think it goes beyond that. For example, let a group isomorphism between elements of a Group $GF(2^m)$. Can this isomorphism go beyond group operations for any given tuple of elements $x_i$ and $x_j$ and perserve function mappings beyond group operations? For example, [continued]

Comment: [continued] for scalar $k$ and ECC generator point $G$, Point $P = k*G$ is a different point for group $GF(2^m)$ if produced under a different irreducible constructing polynomials. My question is if a point like this can indeed perserve more mappings/direct correspondences beyond group operations (for example, both points $P$ to be able to produce the same field trace, or the same Norm, or Half trace results when solving $ z^2 + z = λ$.

Comment: Updated question with comment since I believe it was necessary for further clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to paint a coherent picture while hopefully also answering the question.

Here we use two different polynomials in defining the field $GF(2^{233})$, namely
$$f_1(z)=z^{233}+z^{74}+1\qquad\text{and}\qquad f_2(z)=z^{233}+z^{159}+1.$$
They are both irreducible. Actually it suffices to verify that one is irreducible, because they are each others *reciprocal polynomials*. That is,
$$
z^{233}f_1(\dfrac1z)=f_2(z).\tag{1}
$$
With these two polynomials we can define two variants of $GF(2^{233})$. Namely the fields
$$K_1=GF(2)[z]/\langle f_1(z)\rangle\qquad\text{and}\qquad K_2=GF(2)[z]/\langle f_2(z)\rangle.$$
By the fundamental theorem of finite fields we know that they are isomorphic. The isomorphism is by no means unique (there are $233$ different automorphisms to choose from), but one of them stands out because of $(1)$. If we denote the natural generators $\alpha=z+\langle f_1(z)\rangle\in K_1$ and $\beta=z+\langle f_2(x)\rangle\in K_2$, then, all because of $(1)$, we have an isomorphism $\sigma:K_1\to K_2$ uniquely determined by $\sigma(\alpha)=1/\beta$. This is because $(1)$ says that $1/\beta$ is a root of $f_1(z)$ as is $\alpha$, and an isomorphism of fields must observe such polynomial relations.

---

If we look at an elliptic curve

$$E:y^2+a_1 xy+a_3 y=x^3+a_2 x^2+a_4 x+a_6,\tag{2}$$ where $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6\in K_1$, then we can think of the "same" curve as being defined over $K_2$, if we apply the isomorphism $\sigma$ everywhere. We end with
$$
E':y^2+a_1' xy+a_3' y=x^3+a_2' x^2+a_4' x+a_6',\tag{2'}
$$
where $a_i'=\sigma(a_i)\in K_2$ for all indices $i$. In other words, we replace the coefficients $a_i\in K_1$ with their isomorphic images in $K_2$.

As isomorphisms of fields respect the arithmetic operations, it immediately follows that if a point $P=(x,y)\in K_1\times K_1$ lies on the curve $E$, then $P'=(x',y')\in K_2\times K_2, x'=\sigma(x), y'=\sigma(y)$, is a point on the curve $E'$.

Furthermore, field automorphisms also take lines in $K_1\times K_1$ to lines in $K_2\times K_2$, and this implies that the above mapping (still call it $\sigma$) also takes the addition of $E$ to addition of $E'$, so it is automatically also an isomorphism of the underlying groups of the two elliptic curves. So if $k$ is an integer and $Q=k*P=(u,v)\in E$ is an integer multiple of $P$, then $Q'=k*P'=(u',v')$ where $u'=\sigma(u),v'=\sigma(v)$.

> An isomorphism between the underlying fields automatically produces an isomorphism of elliptic curves and their group structures *provided that you also apply the isomorphism to the coefficients of the defining equation* (like the passage from $E$ to $E'$ above).

---

Recording the following, just in case. Putting on my algebra teacher's hat :-). A mistake often made by people not well versed in the language of quotient rings of polynomial rings is to equate the coset $z+\langle f_1(z)\rangle$ with the polynomial $z$. Thinking that $z$ could be an element of $K_1$. The following confusion then rears its ugly head. This element is totally unrelated to the element $z+\langle f_2(z)\rangle\in K_2$. The reason I denoted them by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively is exactly to avoid this confusion.
It is sometimes convenient to denote the coset of $z$ by $z$ as well, but you can only do this if the field description never changes. Compare with modular arithmetic. Modulo $11$ the coset of $2$ (similarly often just denoted $2$) really is
$$\overline{2}=\{2,13,24,35,\ldots,-9,-20,-31,\ldots\}$$
but "the same" coset of $2$ modulo $13$ looks like
$$\overline{2}=\{2,15,28,41,\ldots,-11,-24,-37,\ldots\},$$
a totally different animal. It's the same thing with cosets of polynomials.

Caveat: More often than not when there are two alternative definitions of a finite field, the relation between the respective zeros of the two polynomials is more complicated. The case of reciprocal polynomials here is very exceptional. I simply could not resist using it.

Comment: Thank you, I follow. Most of them are clear to me already, although the specific example in (1) is interesting. Can you clarify if it follows that, given the isomorphism $σ$ over generators $a$ and $b$ *specifically in cases with two reciprocal polynomials* (as defined by you above), then all mappings between $P$ and $P'$ will produce the same Trace and Norm outputs due to the reciprocal nature of $f_1(z)$ and $f_2(z)$?